# Database query needs a lot of time

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am currently running this query and it takes around 15 sec to load i want to optimize the query

```
SELECT *, `points`.`players` as `players` ,
FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') as `date`,
        (SELECT   `points`.`players`
        FROM `points`
        WHERE   FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') > `date` - INTERVAL 7 DAY 
                AND FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') < `date` - INTERVAL 167 HOUR 
                AND `server_id` = {$server_id} 
                AND `type` = 2 
                LIMIT 1 
        ) as `prevplayers`
FROM `points`
WHERE   `points`.`timestamp` > UNIX_TIMESTAMP(NOW() - INTERVAL 7 DAY) 
        AND `server_id` = {$server_id} 
        AND `type`=2 
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`), '%Y-%m-%d %H') 
ORDER BY DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(`points`.`timestamp`),'%Y-%m-%d %H')
```

Table structure

[image]

Indexes[image]

With Explain Output[image]

Ideal time is 1-2 secs

Any Suggestions?

Thanks
Somdeb

Comment: how do you use indexes in the table?

Comment: by id as primary

Comment: Please describe your table structure and also what is your desire output so it helps others to optimize your query.

Comment: whats your db store engine? have you add  any indexes?excute "EXPLAIN {your sql}" in cli, and show the output

Comment: joins are usually far more efficient than sub-queries

Comment: Try removing the * from the topmost query and see what happens.

Comment: no improvement by removing *

Comment: What will be corresponding join query

Comment: Run explain on the query (put explain before select) and share the output.

Comment: Just an aside - you don't need to do all that processing in the group by and order by clauses.  As the format is applied to all the values, you can simply use the column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you create an additional index with the columns in following order and retry the query?

1. server_id
2. type
3. timestamp (mention descending order)

Comment: By adding Index It make a lot faster